# I used data tables for list populated in JSP file and in jsp file List is not displayed proper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am new to jQuery and Bootstrap . I am using Data tables to displayed data in table format but issue is that when one column data is too long I get horizontal scroll bar as shown in below image:

[image]

below is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <jsp:directive.include file="include_metatags.jsp" />
    <title><s:message code="app.title.transactionlist" arguments="${applicationScope['APPLICATION_HEADER_TEXT']}"/></title>
    <jsp:directive.include file="include_head.jsp" />

    <link href="resources/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body,html{
            background-image      : url("resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg");
            background-attachment : fixed;
            background-position   : center center;
            background-size       : cover;  
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp">
    <jsp:param value="transactions" name="currentpage" />
</jsp:include>
    <div class="container amo2">
        <div class="card card-container2">        

           <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="resources/img/xyymm/fintech_img.png">             
            <h4 style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <s:message code="label.list.transaction"/> 
                </h4>
            <div class="container-fluid mer table-responsive" id="wht">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                      <li><a href="home"><s:message code="app.link.home"/></a></li>
                      <li class="active"><s:message code="form.home.transactionList"/></li>
                </ol> 
                <jsp:directive.include file="alertMessage.jsp" />

                <div class="body-content">

                    <table border="1" id="transactions" class="table table-striped table-responsive dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" aria-describedby="transactions_info">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.transactionId"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.merchantId"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.invoiceNumber"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.amount"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.currency"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.paymentGateway"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.orderStatus"/></td>
                                <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.createdDate"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="transaction" items="${transactionList}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#transactionView" id="transactionsPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"
                                        onclick="viewTransactionDetails('${transaction.transactionId}')">
                                        ${transaction.transactionId}
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>${transaction.merchantId}</td>
                                <td>${transaction.invoiceNum}</td>
                                <td>${transaction.amount}</td>
                                <td>${transaction.currency}</td>
                                <td>${transaction.domainName}</td>
                                <td>${transaction.orderStatus}</td>
                                <td>${transaction.createdDate}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <jsp:include page="transactionListPopup.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="divID" value="transactionView" />
    </jsp:include>

    <jsp:directive.include file="include_body_scripts.jsp" />
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="resources/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#transactions').DataTable({
                    "order": [[7,"asc"]],
                    responsive: true,
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "width" : "10%",
                            "targets": [ 7 ],
                            "visible": false
                        },
                        {
                            "width" : "5%",
                            "targets": [ 1 ],
                            "visible": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            );
        } );

        function viewTransactionDetails(transactionId) {

              return $.ajax({
                    url: 'transactions',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {"transactionId" : transactionId},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (item) {

                        var trMerchantHTML = 'Merchant ID - '+ item.merchantId;
                        var trEmailHTML = 'Pay From Email - '+ item.payFromEmail;
                        var trFirstHTML = 'First Name - '+ item.firstName;
                        var trLastHTML = 'Last Name - '+ item.lastName;
                        var trRelayHTML = 'Relay URL - '+ item.relayUrl;
                        var trInvoiceHTML = 'Invoice Number - '+ item.invoiceNum;
                        var trAmountHTML = 'Amount - '+ item.amount;
                        var trCustomerHTML = 'Customer ID - '+ item.customerId;
                        var trIPHTML = 'IP Address - '+ item.ipAddress;
                        var trCurrencyHTML = 'Currency - '+ item.currency;
                        var trDomainHTML = 'Domain Name - '+ item.domainName;
                        var trOrdersHTML = 'Order Status - '+ item.orderStatus;
                        var trRedirectHTML = 'Is Redirect - '+ item.isredirect;
                        var trTransMsgHTML = 'Transaction Message - '+ item.txn_message;
                        var trMerchOrderIdHTML = 'Merchant Order ID - '+ item.merch_order_id;
                        var trMerchTransIdHTML = 'Merchant Transaction ID - '+ item.merch_txn_id;
                        var trActionHTML = 'Action - '+ item.action;

                        $('#merchantID').html(trMerchantHTML);
                        $('#payFromEmailID').html(trEmailHTML);
                        $('#firstNameID').html(trFirstHTML);
                        $('#lastNameID').html(trLastHTML);
                        $('#relayUrlID').html(trRelayHTML);
                        $('#invoiceNumberID').html(trInvoiceHTML);
                        $('#amountID').html(trAmountHTML);
                        $('#customerID').html(trCustomerHTML);
                        $('#ipAddressID').html(trIPHTML);
                        $('#currencyID').html(trCurrencyHTML);
                        $('#domainNameID').html(trDomainHTML);
                        $('#orderStatusID').html(trOrdersHTML);
                        $('#isRedirectID').html(trRedirectHTML);
                        $('#txnMessage').html(trTransMsgHTML);
                        $('#merchantOrderID').html(trMerchOrderIdHTML);
                        $('#merchantTransID').html(trMerchTransIdHTML);
                        $('#action').html(trActionHTML);
                    }, 
                    error: function() {
                        $('#transactionView_Table ').html('<p>An error has occurred.</p>');
                    }
             });
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't want Scroll bar Can anybody has idea how to break column values in 2 or more lines means in above image there is MerchantID column and I want to show data in this column in two or more lines.

Is there any property in data tables which decreases width of particular column?

Please anybody can help me to get this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share some relevant code

Comment: I share my code you can go through it and find if any solution relevant to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer for my question.

```
<td>${transaction.merchantId}</td>
```

added style for break line as given below:

```
<td style="word-break: break-all;word-break: breakword;width:15%;"> ${transaction.merchantId}</td>
```

here we can adjust width according to our data consumption. one can add this style in all required columns.